# Installing PostgreSQL 9.0 on FreeBSD

Tags: postgresql, freebsd

My installation of `databases/postgresql90-client` fails on a FreeBSD box.

The installation blocks on `configure`, at the following step (while CPU usage tops 100%):

```
checking thread safety of required library functions...
```

The last lines of `/usr/ports/databases/postgresql90-client/work/postgresql-9.0.4/config.log` are:

```
... a couple of defines ...
#define USE_SYSV_SEMAPHORES 1
#define USE_SYSV_SHARED_MEMORY 1
#define MEMSET_LOOP_LIMIT 1024

configure: caught signal 2
configure: exit 1
```

(the exit is due to the ^C of my part).

You can find the complete file here: https://gist.github.com/1093873

The system details are:

```
## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = nsxxxxxx.ovh.net
uname -m = i386
uname -r = 7.4-RELEASE
uname -s = FreeBSD
uname -v = FreeBSD 7.4-RELEASE #0: Thu Feb 17 03:51:56 UTC 2011     root@walker.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC 

/usr/bin/uname -p = i386
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**General steps for troubleshooting FreeBSD ports**

1. `make clean`
2. Try building the port again.
3. If it fails: Did it fail in the same place? If not, consider the possibility you may have bad RAM.
4. [See if anyone else has had a similar problem](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/query-pr-summary.cgi)
5. If not, [Submit a problem report](http://www.freebsd.org/send-pr.html) or ask on the ports mailing list/contact the port maintainer.

If you get to step 5 please read, understand and internalize [these wonderful instructions](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/articles/problem-reports/article.html) on how to submit useful problem reports prior to submitting one.  Following those guidelines is *very* helpful :-)

(You can also cop out and build Postgres from source by hand, which is what I typically do - I prefer to install Postgres in a self-contained directory like `/usr/local/pgsql`, which is annoying to do via ports.)